# Button to go from page to page

Tags: javascript, canvas, transition

So I've looked around at page to page functions and have seen mixed techniques.

I have a full canvas animation with clicking and keyboard functionality and all, but I want to have a screen prior that is blank and just has a button that says Start.

Would I have to make a new html file?  Or a function that clears the canvas and has the button on it that transitions to the animation?  And how does the general set up for that look like?

Comment: You could even have a div that is positioned against the canvas, both under the same dom. When clicked, the div is set to invisible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Same Page Solution**

 Create a `div` container. Make everything in the container have display none except for the start button. When the start button is pressed, a JS function is run which sets everything in the container to the proper display property and makes the start button invisible. Not that manipulating the DOM is a costly operation and should be done sparingly. http://jsfiddle.net/qrj3Lxb5/1/

**HTML**

```
<body>
  <div>
    <canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
    <button id="btn" onclick="start(this.id)">Start</button>
  </div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
#myCanvas {
  display: none
}

#btn {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center
}

html {
  height: 100%
}

body {
  height: 100%
}
```

**JS**
var start = function(id) {
  var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
  c.style.display = "inline-block";
  var btn = document.getElementById(id);
  btn.style.display = "none";
}

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
  var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(95, 50, 40, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  ctx.stroke();
});
```

You can alternatively have a new html page for the canvas. Up to you.

Comment: Really helpful! I definitely prefer this over having a new html page.

The relationship between function and button was what was messing me up, but I think I get it now.

Comment: If you like this you should check out JavaScript SPA (Single Page Application) Frameworks like AngularJS or React. Once you learn how to use them its soooo easy to do stuff like this.